# Converting str data to file object in Python

Tags: python, json, file, object, typeconverter

I am posting videos to Google Cloud Buckets and a signed PUT url does the trick. However, if the file size is greater than 10MB it will not work, so I found an open source that will allow me to do this however, it uses a file like object.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=65536):
while True:
    data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data

def main(file, url):
content_name = str(file)
content_path = os.path.abspath(file)
content_size = os.stat(content_path).st_size

print content_name, content_path, content_size

f = open(content_path)

index = 0
offset = 0
headers = {}

for chunk in read_in_chunks(f):
    offset = index + len(chunk)
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    headers['Content-length'] = content_size
    headers['Content-Range'] = 'bytes %s-%s/%s' % (index, offset, content_size)
    index = offset
    try:
        r = requests.put(url, data=chunk, headers=headers)
        print "r: %s, Content-Range: %s" % (r, headers['Content-Range'])
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

The way that I was uploading videos was passing in json formatted data.

```
class GetData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    data = self.request.get('file')
```

Then all I did was a request.put(url, data=data). This worked seamlessly.

How do I convert this data, that Python recognizes as str to a file like object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A so called 'file-like' object is in most cases just an object that implements the Python buffer interface; that is, has methods like `read`, `write`, `seek`, and so on.

The standard library module for buffer interface tools is called [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). You're looking for either [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) or [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), depending on the type of data you have — if it's a unicode encoded string, you're supposed to use `io.StringIO`, but you're probably working with a raw bytestream (such as in an image file) as opposed to just text, so `io.BytesIO` is what you're looking for. When working with files, this is the same distinction as doing `open(path, 'r')` for unicode files and `open(path, 'rb')` for raw processing of the bytes.

Both classes take the data for the file-like object as the first parameter, so you just do:

```
f = io.BytesIO(b'test data')
```

After this, `f` will be an object that works just like a file, except for the fact that it holds its data in memory as opposed to on disk.

Comment: Thank You, This was the solution. Now I just have to figure out why I got a 400 response. But thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
data= StringIO(data)
read_in_chunks(data)
```

Comment: This solution does not work under Python 3, you need to use the `io` module instead. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Underyx...OP seems to be working with Python2 instead!

Comment: @IronFist yes, and it is a shame. Either way, this question will probably not be found exclusively by Python 2 users, so it's important to note that one of the answers is compatible with both versions and the other isn't.