# Python3 convert byte object to file object

Tags: python-3.x, file, io, byte, read-write

I am using an API that only takes file objects (a BufferedRandom object returned by `open(file_name, 'r+b')`).

However, what I have in hand is a variable (bytes object, returned by `with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
                                                              file.read()`)

I am wondering how to convert this bytes object into the BufferedRandom object to serve as input of the API, because if I input the bytes object as input to the API function, I got the error "bytes" object has no attribute "read".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587699/converting-str-data-to-file-object-in-python).

You can get your bytes data into a file object with this:

```
import io
f = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes_data)
```

Now `f` behaves just like a file object with methods like `read`, `seek` etc.
I had a similar issue when I needed to download (export) files from one REDCap database and upload (import) them into another using [PyCap](https://pycap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The `export_file` method returns the file contents as a raw bytestream, while `import_file` needs a file object. Works with Python 3.